# Jquery Isotope: 'width2' class breaks the layout of the remaining elements

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am attempting to use JQuery Isotope to layout elements that are the result of a search query. The idea is to have a 2-column layout showing little boxes with the returned search items.

Everything is pretty much working except for one aspect.

When a user types a search phrase, and an exact match is found, my goal is to have the associated element appear at 100% (1 column) at the top and to have the remaining items continue their 50% (2 column) layout afterwards. However, it seems the exact match (100%) item is throwing off the layout of the following items, causing them to line up in a single column at 50% width.

Now, when I do a search, a NO exact match is found, the 2 column layout works perfectly fine.

**There is a lot of Code which I will add to the bottom of this post, but I made a CodePen sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjKrpB**

If you comment out the style for the `.grid-item--width2` item in the CSS, or just remove the `grid-item--width2` class from the first `grid-item` element, you will see the correct layout.

Any assistance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head against a wall for hours, and I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking!

PS - If it is thought to be relevant, I am using BOOTSTRAP as well.

Thanks everyone!

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center" style="margin: 20px;">
  <div>Filter Search Results:</div>
  <div class="btn btn-md btn-primary" onclick="$grid.isotope({ filter: '.grid-item' });">All</div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="system btn btn-md btn-primary" onclick="$grid.isotope({ filter: '.system' });">Systems</div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="part btn btn-md btn-primary" onclick="$grid.isotope({ filter: '.part' });">Inventory Items</div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="specsheet btn btn-md btn-primary" onclick="$grid.isotope({ filter: '.specsheet' });">Spec. Sheets</div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="diagram btn btn-md btn-primary" onclick="$grid.isotope({ filter: '.diagram' });">Wiring/Diagrams</div>
</div>

<div class='row' id='schresults' style='margin:0 15px;'>
  <div class='grid-item grid-item--width2 part'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row exact'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive md' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-red'>100%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <h2>Exact Match!</h2>
          <a href='#'><b>Inventory Item Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>

          <div class="row" style="margin:20px 0;">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-lg" href='#' style="color: #fff;margin:0;"><i class='fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa'
                                            style=
                                            "margin-right: 15px;"></i> View
                This Part</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='grid-item part'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-orange'>77%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <a href='#'><b>Inventory Item Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='grid-item specsheet'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-gray'>28%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <a href='#'><b>Spec. Sheet Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='grid-item diagram'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-gray'>27%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <a href='#'><b>Wiring Diagram Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='grid-item diagram'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-gray'>25%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <a href='#'><b>Wiring Diagram Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='grid-item diagram'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-gray'>25%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <a href='#'><b>Wiring Diagram Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='grid-item diagram'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-gray'>25%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <a href='#'><b>Wiring Diagram Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='grid-item diagram'>
    <div class='grid-item-body'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
          <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

          <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
            <span class='label bg-gray'>20%</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
          <a href='#'><b>Wiring Diagram Title</b></a>
          <br>
          <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class='grid-item system'>
      <div class='grid-item-body'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
            <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

            <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
              <span class='label bg-gray'>8%</span>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
            <a href='#'><b>System Title</b></a>
            <br>
            <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class='grid-item system'>
      <div class='grid-item-body'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
            <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

            <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
              <span class='label bg-gray'>8%</span>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
            <a href='#'><b>System Title</b></a>
            <br>
            <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class='grid-item specsheet'>
      <div class='grid-item-body'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3 text-center'>
            <img class='img-responsive' src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' style='margin:0 auto;'>

            <div style='margin-top:15px;font-size:1.2em'>
              <span class='label bg-gray'>8%</span>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-9'>
            <a href='#'><b>Spec. Sheet Title</b></a>
            <br>
            <small>Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description Item Description </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{background:#aaa;}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  background:#ff0;
}

.grid-item--width2 {
   width: 100%;
}

.grid-item-body {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var $grid = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $grid = $('#schresults');    
  $grid.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });         

    if ($('.grid-item.part').length>0) $('.btn.part').show();
    if ($('.grid-item.specsheet').length>0) $('.btn.specsheet').show();
    if ($('.grid-item.diagram').length>0) $('.btn.diagram').show();
    if ($('.grid-item.system').length>0) $('.btn.system').show();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following changes should fix

```
var $grid = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $grid = $('#schresults');
    $grid.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
        }
    });
});
```

**If columnWidth is not set, Isotope will use the outer width of the first item.**

*add css block*

```
.grid-sizer {
  width: 50%;
}
```

*.grid-sizer empty element, only used for element sizing should be under **#schresults***

```
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
```

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#columnwidth

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpwerG